# How to remove a CSS style completely and not replacing it?

Tags: css

I have a style given in the following way:

```
td,th{padding:0}
```

Now I want to completely remove this style dynamically and not override it with some value because I need the `inline/default` value set by the browser. Anyone having any idea how to do this, feel free to answer.

Comment: 'Remove this style dynamically'? how is it generated? If you want to remove it, remove it.

Comment: What do you mean by inline style? Do you mean via a style attribute? Or simply reset the style back to browser defaults? Why would you want to remove the style anyway?

Comment: inline will override stylesheet because it's the most specific

Comment: If you want to remove it, you should remove the source which added it (e.g. the code in file, a JS script etc.). If you want to override the value with default / parent's value, then you can use `td[style],th[style]{padding:inherit !important;}`. If the code is not inline, you just need `td,th{padding:inherit;}` further down the CSS file or inline if you don't want to remove existing code.

Answer (score 3):

In CSS 3, you might want to use

```
th,td { padding: unset; }
```

or

```
th,td { padding: initial; }
```

> http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-inheritance-tips-tricks/
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherit-initial

Answer (score 2):

Try making the value initial ie. Set the value to padding: initial